# Convert a number into a special datetime

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Date1 :20061201
Date2 :01/12/2006

How could use pandas in Python to convert date1 into date2(day/month/year) format?Thanks!Date1 and Date2 are two column in csv files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Data:**

```
In [151]: df
Out[151]:
       Date
0  20061201
1  20170530
```

**Option 1:**

```
In [152]: pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%Y%m%d').dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
Out[152]:
0    01/12/2006
1    30/05/2017
Name: Date, dtype: object
```

**Option 2:**

```
In [153]: df.Date.astype(str).str.replace('(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})', r'\3/\2/\1')
Out[153]:
0    01/12/2006
1    30/05/2017
Name: Date, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `pandas` and want a `timestamp` object back

```
pd.to_datetime('20061201')

Timestamp('2006-12-01 00:00:00')
```

If you want a string back

```
str(pd.to_datetime('20061201').date())

'2006-12-01'
```

---

Assuming you have a dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Date1=['20161201']))
```

Then you can use the same techniques in vectorized form.

**as timestamps**

```
df.assign(Date2=pd.to_datetime(df.Date1))

      Date1       Date2
0  20161201  2016-12-01
```

**as strings**

```
df.assign(Date2=pd.to_datetime(df.Date1).dt.date.astype(str))

      Date1       Date2
0  20161201  2016-12-01
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is probably using the date parsing provided by [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime(str(20061201), "%Y%m%d")
```

You can apply this transformation to all rows in your pandas dataframe/series using the following:

```
from datetime import datetime
def convert_date(d):
    return datetime.strptime(str(d), "%Y%m%d")
df['Date2'] = df.Date1.apply(convert_date)
```

This will add a `Date2` column to your dataframe `df`, which is the datetime representation of the `Date1` column.

You can then serialize the date again by using `strftime`:

```
def serialize_date(d):
    return d.strftime(d, "%d/%m/%Y")
df['Date2'] = df.Date2.apply(serialize_date)
```

Alternatively you can do it all with string manipulations:

```
def reformat_date(d):
    year = d // 10000
    month = d % 10000 // 100
    day = d % 100
    return "{day}/{month}/{year}".format(day=day, month=month, year=year)
df['Date2'] = df.Date1.apply(reformat_date)
```

This is quite a bit faster than using the parsing machinery provided by `strptime`.

Comment: One note: If working on truly large datasets, strptime is quite slow (as it does a lot of extra handling).

Comment: The datetime default shows: Year/Month/Day. But I need the Day/Month/Year output format.Thanks!

Comment: Added a serialization into the desired format and a string manipulation version.

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
A=datetime.datetime.strptime('20061201','%Y%m%d')
A.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use apply and lambda function here.

Suppose you have a dataset named `df` as below:

```
id    date1
0     20061201
2     20061202
```

You can use the code like below:

```
df['date2'] = df['date1'].apply(lambda x: x[6:] + '/' + x[4:6] + '/' + x[:4])
```

The result will be:

```
id      date1      date2
 0     20061201    01/12/2016
 2     20061202    02/12/2016
```